# Translation of German "Es wird nichts so heiß gegessen, wie es gekocht wird"

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests, translation, popular-refrains, proverbs

A German speaker wrote:

> As the German saying goes: You never eat the food as hot as it is
>   cooked.

This is a literal translation of the proverb, "Es wird nichts so heiß gegessen, wie es gekocht wird."  I wasn't the only person who had *never* heard that proverb in English.  To me it *sounded* like a great proverb, but I couldn't quite figure out what it should mean.  When asked to clarify its application to the question at hand, the German explained:

> We don’t take the rules as literally as they are written.

"Wow!" I thought.  "That is a great proverb!  Why can't I think of an English equivalent?"

Out of curiosity I popped the whole saying into Google translate and it came back with, "Nothing is as bad as it looks."  So that doesn't seem right.

Of course German is famous for having a word for everything.  But without falling back on ethnic jokes I can't figure out why a simple proverb like this would not have been translated or have an English analog.

Is there something equivalent, or similar, in English?  Or any great insights into why there wouldn't be?

Comment: *Rules are made to be broken*.

Comment: My old Van Dale dictionary N-E says simply, _Things are never as bad as they seem_.

Comment: @MrLister - So that's a second source that appears to incorrectly translate the German proverb to an English one with a different meaning.  I wonder why that happens?

Comment: Proverbs are notorious for having multiple meanings. That's why they don't translate worth a damn. As they say in Italian, _Traduttore, traditore_.

Comment: @JohnLawler - I know that's *often* true, but in this case when I heard the literal translation I thought, "That sounds like a clever way of saying something, but I can't *quite* figure out *what*."  After being given the meaning I thought, "Sure, that's a clever way of putting it."  I.e., I can easily see the literal translation having not only been adopted in English, but also without any more confusion regarding its meaning than that innate to other common English proverbs.  So I don't think this is a case of, "It doesn't translate."  It *seems* like it *does* translate, but just *hasn't*.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think @JohnLawler was pointing out that proverbs, including this one, can have multiple meanings (even in the language of origin). Are you positive that the meaning given by your German friend is the one and only meaning of the proverb in German and that it means exactly the same thing to all Germans? Judging by the way you're writing off "Things are never as bad as they seem" as an apparent incorrect translation [of the meaning] of the German proverb, it seems that you are assuming that your friend's interpretation is the only valid one, and maybe that's a mistake.

Comment: It does most certainly _not_ mean "Rules are there to be broken". "Things are never as bad as they seem" covers it reasonably well. Now it may happen that things look very bad because of some rule, and you can make them less bad by breaking the rule, but that's not the meaning of the proverb.

Answer (score 4):

In the English subtitles for the 2009 movie "Das Weisse Band,  "his bark is worse than his bite" is used.

Answer (score 4):

It's one of my favourite German sayings (German native speaker), and I also haven't been able to find a good translation for this proverb.

As for the meaning, it's sort of an amalgamation of: "Don't put the cart before the horse" and "Things are never as bad as they seem".

Answer (score 2):

My German is adequate, although not good enough to know whether this conveys the meaning of the phrase, but what about the simple English "take it with a pinch of salt"?

(And it also has a culinary flavour.)

Comment: Not quite. The German saying is actually used in situations where the results of a bad situation are not as dramatic as they appeared at first. (Or where you predict a bad situation to not have as bad a result as it looks now.) You could say "all's well that ends well", but that doesn't quite cover it either.

Comment: @MrLister Oh I see, sort of "Things are never as bad as they seem."

Comment: That's what OP had too, and there may be an overlap, but that's not the gist.

Comment: @MrLister I'll see if I can find examples of the German in context and then return to this. A bit embarrassing as mine is the only answer, bit I prefer to follow the rules and answer in answers rather than comments. I can always modify or withdraw later.

Comment: @MrLister: "All's well that ends well" doesn't cover it, because the situation won't necessary end well, just not as bad as predicted. Let's say you did something really stupid, expect to go to jail for it, and end up with a £500 fine: It didn't end exactly _well_ for you but also not as bad as you initially feared.

Answer (score 1):

perhaps context helps,
I am familiar with the saying as used by those drafting contracts, where the message conveyed is
"strict principles as layed down in contractual clauses are generally not upheld in practice"
we would assume practical reasons, and particular circumstances trump principles themselves etc.
There has to be an equivalent in other languages..

Answer (score 1):

In my personal opinion (austrian german speaking kanguru :)) the food in the phrase "Es wird nichts so heiß gegessen wie es gekocht wird" stands for certain opinions or believes, that are projected onto others.

The phrase therefore rather means "Nothing is as strict as it seems".

For example, a person asking you to uphold certain behavior/believes even though they themselves do not stick to their own word. Then I would say to that person: "Die Supper wird nicht so heiß gegessen, wie sie gekocht wird" - "The soup is not eating as hot as its cooked". This way I am pointing out to the person, that they are not sticking to their own rules.

Just my 2cents. But the beauty of language is, that it is constantly developing and changing, sometimes for the better... :)

Answer (score 0):

It indeed is a great proverb, and the German language has quite a lot of those. (Reference: I'm a native German speaker). And they usually hit the mark. Kind of collective folk wisdom. "You don´t eat your food as hot as you cook it." Right. It seems to me that the simplest way to say this in English would be, "Things are never as bad as they look (as they may seem at first)."
And thanks for this posting!